# Laravel: How can I authenticate a user by e-mail, where the e-mail address is stored in a separate table?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating a website using Laravel and I wish to use the Auth middleware. To let users add multiple e-mail addresses and phone numbers, so they have backup options for recovery etc., I'm storing them in separate tables from the main `users` table.

Looking closer at the Authentication documentation and skimming through some of the classes used for the authentication, I'm unsure how I might specify that the e-mail and phone number should be retrieved from their respective tables rather than the `users` table (`email_addresses` and `phone_numbers`).

If anyone could tell me how to set this up, or at least point me in the right direction, I would be super grateful. Don't need to have it spelled out, but if someone know which files I need to edit that would help a lot.

Comment: Your user will be still in `Users` table right? If so you can have Eloquent Relationships to work with it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi Yes the user is in the `users` table. So if I set up a one-to-many relationship from `User` to `EmailAddress`, `Auth::attempt(['address' => $email, 'password' => $password])` will check for the 'address' attribute on both models automatically?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because Authentication provided with laravel only use one table to authenticate. I was meant to create relationships and then write your own implementation like trait `AuthenticatesUsers`. I don't think there is anything else you can do about it except changing Auth module from laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your user record by email from emails table:

`$record = Emails::where('email', $email)->first();`

```
if($record){
    //if this email is valid you will get the user record
    if(auth()->validate(['id' => $record->user_id, 'password' => $input['password']])) auth()->loginUsingId($record->user_id)
    else echo 'Invalid password';
}
else {
    echo 'User not present!'
}
```

Comment: I figured I'd have to do something like this with manual authentication. Thanks for the answer. :)